# How do I change R's assignment operator to arrow and not equal size

Tags: r-markdown, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

Today during a RStudio session, I accidentally changed the assignment operator in R from arrow to the equal sign. I have no idea how this happened, and now Alt - results in the equal sign all the time. I am on a Mac and my R version is 4.1.1. I am using RMarkdown and only had dplyr and lsa packages installed in this session.

How can I change it back to the arrow operator?

I tried closing and re-opening the file and it doesn't help. Interestingly, the console and R scripts are not affected - this is only happening to RMarkdown

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had issues with Rmarkdown not seeing the chunks as code but text instead - retyping the block quotes fixed the problem!